# No Records Returned after using dplyr and paste0 to summarize and collate results

Tags: r, sql-server, t-sql, dplyr

I've used dplyr and paste0 to summarize data from a TSQL query with the intent to output mean and standard deviation for each column, c1 - c8.  To this end, I created the following stored procedure:

```
Declare @sStudy varchar(50)
Set @sStudy = Convert(Varchar(50),@StudyID)
Declare @inquery nvarchar(max) = N'Select
        c.StudyID, c.RespID, c.ProductNumber, c.ProductSequence, c.BottomScaleValue, 
        c.BottomScaleAnchor, c.TopScaleValue, c.TopScaleAnchor, c.StudyDate,
        c.DayOfWeek, c.A, c.B, c.C, c.D, c.E, c.F,
        c.DependentVarYN, c.VariableAttributeID, c.VarAttributeName, c.[1] as c1, 
        c.[2] as c2, c.[3] as c3, c.[4] as c4, c.[5] as c5, c.[6] as c6, c.[7] as c7, c.[8] as c8
        from ClosedStudyResponses c
        --Sensory Value Attributes only for mean and standard deviation analytics.
        where VariableAttributeID = 1
        and c.StudyID =' +@sStudy ;

BEGIN TRY
        --Insert into CodeMeans
        exec sp_execute_external_script
        @language = N'R',
        @script = N'
        library(dplyr)
        codemeans <- function(StudyID){
            res <- InputDataSet %>%
                group_by (StudyID, ProductNumber) %>%
                summarise_all(.funs=c(mean, sd)) %>%
                setNames(c("StudyID","ProductNumber",
                paste0("c",1:8, "_mean"),
                paste0("c",1:8, "_sd")))
            df <- data.frame(res)
            }
            ',
@input_data_1 = @inquery,
@output_data_1_name = N'df',
@params = N'@StudyID int',
@StudyID = @StudyID
```

When I execute the stored procedure by providing a valid StudyID, the query finishes but contains no data despite the fact that the source table contains data in some if not most of the columns.

How do I modify the above to ensure data is returned?

Comment: You could try adding na.rm = TRUE to your summarize_all() function. mean() and sd() both return NA if there is a single NA value in their input vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason you don't see a result is first of all the fact that you return a function and not a data.frame.

I also think that the syntax of summarize_all should be different (no .funs but funs).

Finally, I'm not sure that the setNames really makes a difference. I believe you have to define your columns outside as well. I would expect the following to work:

```sql
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
    @language = N'R',
    @script = N'
    library(dplyr)

    df <- InputDataSet %>%
            group_by (StudyID, ProductNumber) %>%
            summarise_all(funs(mean, sd)) %>%
            setNames(c("StudyID","ProductNumber",
            paste0("c",1:8, "_mean"),
            paste0("c",1:8, "_sd")))
        ',
    @input_data_1 = @inquery,
    @output_data_1_name = N'df',
    @params = N'@StudyID int',
    @StudyID = @StudyID
    WITH RESULT SETS(("StudyID" int, "ProductNumber" int, "c1_mean" int, 
    "c2_mean" int, "c3_mean" int, 
    "c4_mean" int, "c5_mean" int, "c6_mean" int, "c7_mean" int, "c8_mean" int, 
    "c1_sd" int, "c2_sd" int,
    "c3_sd" int, "c4_sd" int, "c5_sd" int, "c6_sd" int, "c7_sd" int, "c8_sd" int
    ));
```